# The method getString(int) is undefined for the type GamePlay

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, getstring

I'm having a problem while using the `getString` function for reading a string located in the values folder. I get the next error:

> The method getString(int) is undefined for the type GamePlay

It is complicated for me because I want to call this function outside the activity and somehow the structure of the project is quite weird.

My project is a game, while you run the game you run `SampleGame`:

```
public class SampleGame extends AndroidGame
```

It is extended from `AndroidGame` that has the following declaration:

```
public abstract class AndroidGame extends Activity implements Game
```

And the `SampleGame` executes a `SplashLoadingScreen` that has the following declaration:

```
public class SplashLoadingScreen extends Screen
```

The `SpalshLoadingScreen` finally loads some things and then call the `GamePlay`

```
public class GamePlay extends Screen
```

So the `GamePlay` is far from being an `Activity`...

How can I use then the `getString(int)` function?

Comment: Does `GamePlay` or `Screen` have `getString(int)` function? I guess not, and that's the reason for the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `getString(int)` you only need a `Context` object.. You could pass it to your GamePlay object for example having a construcutor `GamePlay(Context c)`, but make sure to pass the Application Context `getApplicationContext()` if you don't need an Activity context, because the GarbageCollector will not be able to collect your Activity if there is a reference to it's context somewhere.